# Rabbit MQ .Net Client 6.1 - Basic Properties Headers are null

Tags: .net, header, rabbitmq, consumer

I was previously using version 5 of the .NET client api for Rabbit.  I would send me messages with custom header by using code similar to this:

```
        IBasicProperties messageProperties = null;
        lock (connectLock)
        {
            messageProperties = this._channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        }
        messageProperties.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>(5);
```

then I would do a BasicPublish, passing the messageProperties object and message body.

my consumer received event would then retrieve the headers from the basic delivery event args i.e.

```
    void consumer_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
    {
        var headers = e.BasicProperties.Headers;
```

However, after I upgraded to the 6.1 library....the Headers object is always NULL.

is there now a different way to retrieve headers using the 6.1 library?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thereis a boolean property IsHeadersPresent which you should possibly check before attempting to access the Headers Collection.

I have a similar problem except I want to add a new Header, I don't really want to have to initialise the Headers Collection myself...

Comment: How is exactly this answer answering the question?